# How to fix Form Designer Not Shown Problem Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, asp.net-core

I'm using vs 2019 16.4.4 version. I created a .net core form application but form desginer doesn't seem. I researched about this bug and i found some instruction. It told that problem can fix changing Use the preview Windows Forms designer for .NET Core apps option but it is not exist in vs. Is there anoter way ?

Comment: [Windows Forms Designer- Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976235/3110834)

Comment: For *Windows Forms - Visual Studio 2019 (16.5 Preview 1 - .NET CORE 3.1)* there is built-in support for designer. Read the instructions in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976235/3110834) or the blog linked in the linked post. For .*NET CORE 3.0*, you may want to download an install designer extension as explained [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core-windows-forms-designer-preview-1/). For *lower versions*, refer to the workaround in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53976235/3110834).