# Visual Studio: "View Designer" missing after porting to .NET Core 3

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, designer, .net-core-3.0

Since i ported our .NET Framework project to .NET Core 3.0 the "View Designer" option in context menu is missing and i cant switch to designer via (SHIFT) F7 anymore. Other way works, so in designer i have the option to switch to C#.

The files are nested correctly and I already tried to re-assign keyboard-bindings, but all without success.

Maybe someone knows how to fix this issue?

best regards

Comment: Today you should upgrade to 3.1, not 3.0.

Comment: @nitg: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using Visual Studio 2019.  Visual Studio 2017 doesn't support WPF designer for .NET Core projects.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975842/windows-forms-designer-and-wpf-designer-for-net-core)