# .netcore - wpf project has no designer window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, .net-4.8

I'm writting a WPF application with .NETCORE but unlike for .NET framework, visual studio doesn't create the designer window somehow, how can I fix this?

Comment: What version of .net core are you using?

Comment: @CristianTeodorov 3.0

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975842/windows-forms-designer-and-wpf-designer-for-net-core), see if this helps. Seems like version of Visual Studio is relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Tools > Options > Xaml Designer > General` and check this:

[image]