# Add reference of System.Windows.forms in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I want to write in my .resx file. I have used ResXResourceWriter which works fine in Windows form but doesn't available in .Net Core application. It needs system.Windows.Forms but .net core don't reference to it.

ResXResourceWriter resx = new  ResXResourceWriter(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\Localization\LabelResource.EN.resx")

Comment: What exactly is your question? System.Windows.Forms does not exist in .net core. If you are looking for localization please see [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I actually want to dump database data into .resx file. Is it possible in .net core?

Comment: The ResXResourceWriter class is not available in .net core, to create one you would need to use .net framework

Comment: Can you please tell me the procedure?

Comment: Not sure what procedure you are talking about, if you want to learn about wrting resource files, look at [System.Resources Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 10):

If you already have .net Core 3.0 (or more) installed and want to add a reference to an existing project (.csproj).

You can only add the following tag:

`<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` into the following section:  `<PropertyGroup>`

**I think it is new: Menu "Edit Project File" in project Contextual Menu in Visual Studio.**

Like so (added into a WPF project):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\GeneralCore\GeneralCore.csproj" />   </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621422/3258851

Answer (score 3):

You will currently need to use the [.Net Core 3.0 Preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0), as System.Windows.Forms is new in .Net Core 3.0. From the [System.Windows.Forms repository](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/Documentation/getting-started.md):

> You can create a new WinForms application with dotnet new command,
>   using the following commands:
>
> ```
> dotnet new winforms -o MyWinFormsApp
> cd MyWinFormsApp
> dotnet run
> ```

Comment: I think I didn't make my question clear enough. Actually, its a web site built on .net core MVC

Comment: Based on the comments in your question, .resx files are just XML files. You should be able to use XDocument to open and change them.