# How to add reference to WinForms if I am developing a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using a third-party nuget package in my WPF project, on .NET 5. When I am trying to call some code, I get such message:
[image: reference to UserControl]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'UserControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

A third-party WPF library references Winforms Class named UserControl.

When I click on yellow-red icon to automatically resolve issue a Reference Manager window opens... I checked StackOverflow and did not find a similar situation. So, what do I do next?
How do I add reference to Winforms library to WPF project on .NET 5?

Comment: To be more specific, mRenderCtrl is of type AnyCAD.WPF.RenderControl, which is `RenderControl : UserControl, IComponentConnector`, in `namespace AnyCAD.WPF`. View3D is of class `RenderControl : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` which is in `namespace AnyCAD.Forms`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

[Add reference of System.Windows.forms in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241072/add-reference-of-system-windows-forms-in-net-core)

So, I had to add this line to my project file:

```
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

Comment: It solved the problem, but I can mark answer only in 2 days