# Using System.Windows.Forms classes in a .net core 3.0 preview9 project

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

How can we use classes like [Screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.screen?view=netcore-3.0) in a .NET Core 3.0 WPF project? There are documentation pages for .NET Core 3.0 for them, so I assumed it should work.

VS and the compiler tell me that the namespace `Forms` does not exist in `System.Windows`, so it feels like the classes are not in the 3.0 sdk.

There is no `System.Windows.Forms` package on nuget, and the "Add reference" dialog has only a `System_Windows_Forms` reference to the .net framework available, which sounds horribly wrong:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/winforms

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` in your csproj.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWpf>true</UseWpf>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: But I'm trying to override some windows controls, like a textbox, in a .Net Core class library project.  These tags don't work in this situation.  How can I get access to the System.Windows.Forms namespace in .Net Core?  I must say this is a bit frustrating.

Comment: are you targetting .net core 3.x?

Comment: Yes.  I figured out that I need to create a new project using the WPF/Windows User Control Library template - and THEN use the <UseWindowsForms> tag shown here.  The template adds the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework to the project.  Is there a way to add a framework to an existing project?

Comment: @MarkBonafe that’s driven by the sdk attribute

Comment: Ok - but me adding to the sdk attribute doesn't "magically" add a framework.

Comment: CORRECTION:  Two comments ago I said a project template, WPF User Control Library, was required.  That was wrong.  The correct template is WPF Custom Control Library (.NET Core).

Comment: @MarkBonafe it seems you have to change `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` to `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">` at the top of your project file.

Comment: That is correct, Mark.  I was absolutely wrong.  Adding to the attribute DOES magically add the framework.  Not a big fan of this style, but it works.