# OpenFileDialog using MvvmCross in a Wpf Core application

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvmcross, openfiledialog

I recently started a small project to freshen up the little wpf knowledge i got and to try out new stuff. I got interested in MvvmCross but I wanted to keep it small for the time being. My goal is a simple image manipulator; image to ascii, recolor and whatnot ...

**My setup:** Mvx Core Library (.NET Standard 2.0)

- MainViewModel - has method OpenFileDialog_Clicked which is fed into openFileDialogCommand

Wpf application (.NET Core 3.1)

- MainView - has a menu with a button that's bound to the openFileDialogCommand on MainViewModel

**The wall I ran into:**
Trying to get a hold of OpenFileDialog (namespace: Microsoft.Win32) to do this:

```
public void OpenFile_Clicked()
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if(result) {
            // big cash prize
        }
    }
```

I specified the namespace because I found several articles talking about missing references on OpenFileDialog. In my case the awnser was .NET Standard. OpenFileDialog just doesn't exist there and that's exactly my problem. How am I supposed to call OpenFileDialog in my ViewModel when the Core library has to be of type .NET Standard? Wouldn't a dependency on the wpf project ruin the entire mvvm pattern?!
To be quite honest: I have read the entire mvx documentation and found a few leads but my wpf/mvvm/xaml understanding extends to maybe a third of it. The MvvmCross Inversion of Control documentation looked useful to me but I still don't get how this would work in my case. The given examples https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc?scroll=43 don't show where these interfaces are located and to me it all breaks down to the fact that I somehow need to get OpenFileDialog out of the wpf project into the core project.

Comment: You should be using the Library Windows.Form.  All Dialogs are a window dll comdlg32.dll (Common Dialog).  The Net Library (and other applications like Excel VBA) create wrappers and call the dll with different parameters (See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/comdlg32.GetOpenFileName).

Comment: @jdweng if i understood correctly, adding:
[DllImport("Comdlg32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetOpenFileName(ref OpenFileName ofn);
to my MainViewModel should get the job done? Great! I will respond a last time when the job is done.

Comment: You should not need to use the DllImport. Not sure why it is missing.   But the Comdlg will work.

Comment: _"MainViewModel - has method OpenFileDialog_Clicked"_ Why? This is not MVVM. The click handler should be in the code-behind of the view. User input in general should not be handled by the view model. User input is the responsibility of the view component (UI).

Comment: Removing this dependency allows you to restrict the library to the .NET Standard compatibility. Otherwise you would force it to be compatible with .NET Framework or .NET Core in order to use the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly.

Comment: You shouldn't make your library depend on UI controls. That's the goal of MVVM. Refactor your API to accept a file path instead, which was acquired by the UI via the dialog.

Comment: @BionicCode excuse my french but what are you talking about? "The click handler should be in the code-behind of the view"? I think you had a little switcheroo there. 
My MainViewModel has the method and command while my MainView binds to it. I think I did everything exactly right.
edit: I also clarified that i did NOT intend to make my core dependant on the wpf project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "@BionicCode excuse my french but what are you talking about? "The
> click handler should be in the code-behind of the view"? I think you
> had a little switcheroo there. My MainViewModel has the method and
> command while my MainView binds to it. I think I did everything
> exactly right. edit: I also clarified that i did NOT intend to make my
> core dependant on the wpf project."

No problem. I think because you are French, you misunderstood me completely.

I will start again: it looks like you are using the MVVM pattern.

To implement MVVM correctly, you must follow some rules (the pattern).
One rule is not to mix responsibilities of the view component with those of the view model component.
Per definition, the view component only displays data to the user and handles user input e.g., collect data or interact with the user.

User input is always part of the user interface (UI). A dialog is a control (application interface) intended to interact with the user. In your case the dialog collects user input (a file path).
That's why this logic belongs to the view => instead of having `OpenFile_Clicked` in your `MainViewModel` only to show the `OpenFileDialog` to the user, `OpenFile_Clicked` should be an event handler in the code-behind of the UI e.g., `MainWindow.xaml.cs`.

This event handler shows the dialog and passes the result (the picked file path) to the `MainViewModel` (using data binding, command pattern or via direct reference).

> "Wouldn't a dependency on the wpf project ruin the entire mvvm
> pattern?!"

No, not the reference to a WPF project would ruin the MVVM pattern, but the reference to the `OpenFileDialog` class.
If you would follow the previously explained principle and remove the dependency to `OpenFileDialog` from your `MainViewModel`, you will get back the advantages of MVVM.
In other words: don't use `OpenFileDialog` or any other view component in `MainViewModel` at all.

> "How am I supposed to call `OpenFileDialog` in my ViewModel when the
> Core library has to be of type .NET Standard?"

Again: don't use `OpenFileDialog` or any other view component in `MainViewModel` at all:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs (WPF .NET Core assembly)**

```
partial class MainWindow
{
  // Event handler for Button.Click
  private void OnOpenDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    dialog.Show();
    string selectedFilePath = dialog.FileName;

    this.ViewModel.HandleSelectedFile(selectedFilePath);
  }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs (.NET Standard library assembly)**

```
public void HandleSelectedFile(string filePath)
{
  // TODO::Handle file e.g. open and read
}
```

Using `OpenFileDialog` forces the referencing assembly to give up the .NET Standard compliance. Because `OpenFileDialog` is a class defined in `System.Windows.Forms`, the referencing assembly requires to use either the .NET Framework or the .NET Core library.
Following the above example will remove this dependency from `MainViewModel` and makes your library to comply to .NET Standard again.

---

> "The MvvmCross Inversion of Control documentation looked useful to me
> but I still don't get how this would work in my case."

Inversion of Control tackles a different problem and has nothing to do with MVVM or showing dialogs from your view model (don't do this). It enables an application to be extensible by exchanging parts.

Since you are using .NET Core you can use the build in IoC container: [Overview of dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#overview-of-dependency-injection)

Comment: You were right, I completely misunderstood you. Even if I'm not French. I was so focused on keeping everything in my core that I didn't even think of anything else. I'm pretty much done for today and don't know if I'll open my project before tomorrow, but I'll provide feedback as soon as I get back to it!
Also, please excuse me for being pissy up there. There was no reason for me being this edgy.

Comment: Worked almost like a charm. I ran into 3 issues and i would like to ask you about one of them. 1. MvxWindow doesn't display anything so I moved the handler to my MainView (works just as fine since it's also located in the wpf project). 2. I tried using a mvx:Bi.nd instead of the standard "Click" -> doesn't work for some reason so I moved back to a "Click". 3. This: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908184/using-system-windows-forms-classes-in-a-net-core-3-0-preview9-project). This looked ugly to me so I just used Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog instead. Is there a problem with that?!

Comment: I just realized how stupid [2.] was. The entire purpose of mvx:Bi.nd is to address the viewmodel ...

Comment: `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` is the recommended dialog to use in context of a WPF application. It doesn't require to reference WindowsForms assemblies. [1] The way I understood your application structure, the click handler should be in `MainView`. [2] There is no scenario for data binding. Click handler to handle the event is just perfect.