# Can't use System.Windows.Forms for WPF application and can't add it in dependencies?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, dependencies

So I am trying to build out a simple project but am really confused on why I can't add

```
using System.Windows.Forms
```

to my MainWindow.xamls.cs file. Every post points to right-clicking on dependencies and adding it in that way. But my reference manager is just blank:
[image: nothing to select]

I understand that I need to add System.Windows.Forms.dll somehow, but after looking around for awhile I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using target framework .NET core 3.1.

I need to use this import so that I can access this class for my project:

```
FolderBrowserDialog
```

Comment: IIRC Windows forms is not supported on .NET Core 3.1. You need to use .NET 5.0 or later. And there, it's also not done using the reference manager, but over a project file setting.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution here. Very confusing stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460253/how-to-use-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-class-library