# How can I add System.Windows.Forms to WPF application when adding via reference/Depenency doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, visual-studio

Following every guide everywhere:

- Step 1:

[image]

- Step 2: it works! Huzzah! Except that it doesn't. Instead I get yellow triangles:

[image]

This project is tiny for now because I only just started. The guides about yellow triangles talk about conflicts which can't be the case here. I have next to nothing imported or used yet:

[image]

Comment: Just noticed this warning in the console area: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently this is due to using .Net Core and Microsoft couldn't anticipate that people would want to use forms in the new normal...

I found this:
[How to use System.Windows.Forms in .NET Core class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38460253/how-to-use-system-windows-forms-in-net-core-class-library)

This is what worked:

- Removed reference/dependancy entirely
- Right-click project, Unload
- Right-click project, Edit project file
- Add the following:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

- Reload project file
- Add "using system.windows.forms" to the top.

Comment: Hi not_a_generic_user, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! C# WPF .NET 6.0

Answer (score 8):

No reference needed.
just go to application properties and activate **Enable Windows Forms for this project**

[image: image description]