# SHGetSpecialFolderLocation with CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS does not show subdirectories in SHBrowseForFolder()

Tags: c#, winapi

I use `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()` to determine the IDCList entry for a special directory:

```
_ = Win32API.Shell32.SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(hWndWindow, (int)RootDirectory, out IntPtr pidlRoot); // Determine IDCList for the root directory via a special directory listing
```

I then display it as the root directory in a directory dialog using `SHBrowseForFolder()`:

```
pidlRet = Win32API.Shell32.SHBrowseForFolder(ref bi); // Show directory dialog
```

However, when I run this for e.g. `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS` (0x005), the root directory points to an empty directory structure, although there are subdirectories in MyDocuments (see image).

The return value (PIDCList) of the directory dialog whose directory I'm querying with `SHGetPathFromIDList()`:

```
SHGetPathFromIDList(IDList, sb))
```

refers to a directory that does not exist:

> C:\Users\fred.aurich\Documents

the user document directory is:

> C:\Benutzer\fred.aurich\Dokumente

Is that possibly the cause? Or how do I get the subfolders displayed in the directory dialog via `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS`???

Folder Browser and result:

[image]

Inclusion of the Forms assembly:

[image]

- Internet research
- Display of subfolders

Comment: From the docs "As of Windows Vista, these values have been replaced by KNOWNFOLDERID values. See that topic for a list of the new constants and their corresponding CSIDL values." So you need to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. Also why don't you just use `Environment.GetFolderPath` and `FolderBrowserDialog` which does all this for you?

Comment: @Charlieface Hello Charlieface! **Thanks** for your hints! I can't use the FolderBrowserDialog **anymore** because the **Forms** NameSpace can only be integrated very poorly in a WPF Dot-Net Core project!
SHGetKnownFolderPath doesn't give me a (pointer to) a PIDCList object that I can then pass to the BROWSEINFO structure of the pidlRoot property to ultimately pass to the SHBrowseForFolder method.

Is there perhaps a conversion from a pointer to a path (*ppszPath) to a PIDCList entry?

Comment: I found something now: `ILCreateFromPath(shlobj_core.h)` in conjunction with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)` should implement my requirement.

Comment: I'm not really convinced about your insistence "the Forms NameSpace can only be integrated very poorly in a WPF Dot-Net Core project", it's just a matter of adding the right package and reference. But have you tried with the `FOLDERID_Documents` Guid using `SHGetKnownFolderIDList`? Yes you can use `ILCreateFromPath` as well. I hope you are freeing the `PIDCList` using `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`

Comment: To quickly explain the problem of integrating Forms-NameSpace:

The solution should be:
1. Add the entry: <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> to the project file.
2. Add the FormsNamespace to the project.

to 1.
My project file looks like this:

<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
   <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   <ApplicationIcon>DVD-Management-2.ico</ApplicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>

End Part 1

Comment: And what happened when you did that, did it not work? Also have you considered upgrading to a supported version of .NET such as .NET 6

Comment: Part 2: 

to 2. When adding the assembly reference, there is only the entry: System_Windows_Forms with underscores instead of dots and the assembly refers to a *.tlb instead of *.dll.

If you have integrated this into the project, you will get the error message (the next time you open the project):

Warning MSB3290 Failed to build wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". The "System_Windows_Forms" type library cannot be imported as a CLR assembly because it was exported from a CLR assembly.

And the Forms NameSpace is not available.

Comment: **Thank you for your hints!** I'll see if `ILCreateFromPath(shlobj_core.h)` can help me. This is very easy and then also works in all my other core projects.

Comment: Now I forgot the picture when integrating the forms assembly!

Oh, that doesn't work in the comments, then I'll try it in the question

Comment: Don't add the COM reference, that's the wrong thing. The SDK should add the .NET reference automatically if you have `UseWindowsForms`. But you may need to unload and reload the project. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72058801/14868997

Comment: ILCreateFromPath works wonderfully, so the RootDirectory call turns into a 1 line:
`IntPtr pidlRoot = GetPIDCLIst(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));`
with:`private static IntPtr GetPIDCLIst(string directory){
   IntPtr pidl = IntPtr.Zero; // Initialize PIDCList entry
   try { pidl = Win32API.Shell32.ILCreateFromPath(directory); }
   finally { Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pidl); }
   return pidl;
}` According to the motto: Less is more! Yep, the Forms NameSpace is available with just the project file modification!**Thank you again for the many insights!**

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question