# Why it is so difficult to have a simple OpenFolder Dialog in WPF .NET 7.0 type of project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2022

Another absolute brain eater is, it is so difficult to have a simple OpenFolder Dialog in WPF .NET 7.0.

I have following configuration in my WPF project file. VS2022 Version 17.5.1

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
```

In Order to use OpenFolder dialog...

1. -- if i Add System.Windows.Forms.dll, kicks of error in most lines of existing code.
2. -- Microsoft.Win32 only has OpenFile And SaveFile dialog,   makes no sense.
3. -- So many fork of Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack that its difficult to find which is original from MSFT.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-wpf

Comment: If you want to use the Winforms FolderBrowserDialog then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60621422/17034).

Comment: Follow this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenFolder dialog is a part of Windows Forms. Add this to your csproj:

```
// other stuff
<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
```

Comment: OK I have that, and now what should I do to get OpenFolderDialog compiling ?